# vba pasting a range on the next row when there are blanks in row above

Tags: vba, excel, range, rows, copy-paste

Hello i am trying to figure out how to paste a range of cells on to the next row when there are a few blanks in the row above. My code keeps overwriting them.
Here is my code:

```
 Sub GetSheetstest()

   Dim Path As String
   Dim FileName As String
   Dim Sheet As Worksheet
   Dim pasteRow As Integer

   pasteRow = 2

  With Application
           .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

Windows("Data .xlsm").Activate

 With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With


Path = "C:\blahz\"
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
Do While FileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True

    Sheets("Case Summary").Range("B2:B46").Copy
    Windows("Summary  Data v4.xlsm").Activate

    Range("A" & pasteRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True


     Workbooks(FileName).Activate

    Sheets("pear").Range("B2:B5").Copy
    Windows("Summary Data v4.xlsm").Activate

   Range("AT" & pasteRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True


         Workbooks(FileName).Activate

    Sheets(" apple").Range("B2:B18").Copy
    Windows("Summary  Data v4.xlsm").Activate

   Range("AX" & pasteRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True



       Workbooks(FileName).Activate

    Sheets("orange").Range("B2:B22").Copy
    Windows(" Summary data v4.xlsm").Activate

   Range("BO" & pasteRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

      pasteRow = pasteRow + 1

    Workbooks(FileName).Close
    FileName = Dir()



Loop

With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

For example, for the sheet pear the majority of the time the range B2:B5 is empty but if there is a value instead of going on the correct row it goes to the top row since there are all the rows above are blank.

Comment: You're using `pasteRow` which starts at 2 and then goes up by 1 each time you loop. What are you expecting?

Comment: Basically, when I am using pasteRow it doesn't paste the values to the correct row if the row above is blank. It goes straight to the first blank row which is means it is not matching the its reference number. There are a lot of blank values for some of the variable that is why it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub GetSheetstest()

    Const F_PATH As String = "C:\blahz\"
    Dim FileName As String, shtDest As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, pasteRow As Long

    Set shtDest = Workbooks("Summary Data v4.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    shtDest.Rows(2 & ":" & shtDest.Rows.Count).Delete

    pasteRow = 2
    FileName = Dir(F_PATH & "*.xlsm")
    Do While FileName <> ""

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=F_PATH & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

        CopyTranspose wb.Sheets("Case Summary").Range("B2:B46"), shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "A")
        CopyTranspose wb.Sheets("pear").Range("B2:B5"), shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "AT")
        CopyTranspose wb.Sheets("apple").Range("B2:B18"), shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "AX")
        CopyTranspose wb.Sheets("orange").Range("B2:B22"), shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "BO")

        pasteRow = pasteRow + 1

        wb.Close False
    Loop
End Sub

'utility: copy a range's values (transposed) to another location
Sub CopyTranspose(rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range)
    rngDest.Resize(rngCopy.Columns.Count, rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = _
               Application.Transpose(rngCopy.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I having been trying to fix this for the past couple of days.